# Cannot wrap a horizontal scrollable ListView in a Column

Tags: listview, containers, flutter, expandable

I am trying to create the following UI in Flutter.

[image]

Here is what my code looks like and the corresponding output.

```
body: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        getTabs(),
        new Container(
          child: Expanded(
            child: new ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => new Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: new Stack(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: new Container(
                              width: 60.0,
                              height: 60.0,
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                image: new DecorationImage(
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                    image: new NetworkImage(
                                        "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/916384996092448768/PF1TSFOE_400x400.jpg")),
                              ),
                              //margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          index == 0
                              ? Positioned(
                                  right: 10.0,
                                  bottom: 10.0,
                                  child: new CircleAvatar(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                                    radius: 10.0,
                                    child: new Icon(
                                      Icons.add,
                                      size: 14.0,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ))
                              : new Container()
                        ],
                      ),
                ),

            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Here is what I get after this code works.

[image]

The list works fine. I can even scroll it but as soon as I try to wrap it in a column, I get errors. I want to wrap it in a column so I can add some widgets just before the list. I cannot wrap it inside any other widget. It would make sense if I could wrap this listview inside a Card. Am I missing something?

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded. When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example, if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction. These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent. Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I answered a similar question yesterday

https://stackoverflow.com/q/50766553/1027843

Answer (score 3):

Put `Expanded` around the `Container` containing the `ListView`, not around the `ListView` itself.

Comment: I did that. I still get the error when I try to put the `Expanded` in a `Column` or `Card`?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices :
Set a height for the column or put the expanded.