# How to create a Chatbot with response options in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dialogflow-es

See the image below:
[image: example]

How Can I implement auto responses using DialogFlow or any other chatbot frameworks in flutter.

I just want to know the method to get the desired result highlighted in the red region.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Using [dialogflow_v2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dialogflow#dialogflow-v2) it seems you could do something like this to get custom suggestions:

In the Dialogflow console you could add a custom payload to your messages, like this:

```
{"suggestions": ["Reply 1", "Reply 2"]}
```

Create a `BotSuggestions` class:

```
class BotSuggestions {
  List<String> suggestions = [];

  BotSuggestions(List<dynamic> messages) {
    messages.forEach((message) {
      if (message['payload'] != null) {
        List<dynamic> suggestionList = message['payload']['suggestions'];
        suggestionList.forEach((suggestion) => suggestions.add(suggestion));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then, you could use it like this:

```
var botSuggestions = BotSuggestions(response.getListMessage());
print(botSuggestions.suggestions);
```

---

Here is a complete example of how to use it:

```
var userMessage = "Hi!!!";
print('User: $userMessage');
response = await dialogflow.detectIntent(userMessage);
var botSuggestions = BotSuggestions(response.getListMessage());
print('Bot: ${response.getMessage()}');
print('Suggestions: ${botSuggestions.suggestions}');

userMessage = botSuggestions.suggestions.first;
print('User: $userMessage');
response = await dialogflow.detectIntent(userMessage);
botSuggestions = BotSuggestions(response.getListMessage());
print('Bot: ${response.getMessage()}');
print('Suggestions: ${botSuggestions.suggestions}');
```

And this would be the output:

> I/flutter ( 5917): User: Hi!!!
>
> I/flutter ( 5917): Bot: Hi! How are you doing?
>
> I/flutter ( 5917): Suggestions: [Reply 1, Reply 2]
>
> I/flutter ( 5917): User: Reply 1
>
> I/flutter ( 5917): Bot: Sorry, what was that?
>
> I/flutter ( 5917): Suggestions: []

---

I asked about this in the package repository to see if there's another way to do it, here you can follow the thread: [How to get suggestions in v2?](https://github.com/VictorRancesCode/flutter_dialogflow/issues/15).

Comment: How could make this feature available?

Comment: As I told you in the answer, you could post an issue in the package to get someone to look at it and also you could try to make it work with the information I provided.

Comment: That looks pretty hard to me, can you pls help me a little more

Comment: I dont think So i just used it 2 months ago was it there at that time?

Comment: flutter_dialogflow: ^0.1.2 this is what I am using

Comment: I edited my answer, it seems to be a way to get the suggestions. The package is okay, you just have to configure something to use the v2: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dialogflow#dialogflow-v2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201784/discussion-between-maadhav-sharma-and-pablo-barrera).

Answer (score 2):

**I may recommend u this guide**

1. Here you will learn how to use dialogflow to your app

   https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-and-bots-dialogflow-d490fc7e5aaf
2. Here you will learn how to use **Chip widget** in flutter

   https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Chip-class.html
3. Sample code

   [how to create horizontal and vertical scrollable widgets in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766553/how-to-create-horizontal-and-vertical-scrollable-widgets-in-flutter)

I hope all This Will help you.

Comment: I have learnt to make a chat bot using dialogue flow. But how to give particular options to the user according to the question asked by the bot?

Comment: @Maadhav.. Did  you find a solution?. I have to create a similar UI where the response contains the red box items you highlighted

Comment: @user2570135 unfortunately I had to stop that project due to the plugin being not completely developed. So do let me know if you find a proper solution, thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can use dialogflow to generate the reponse for the bot, then add the chip widegt to represent an actionable button as below:

```
Chip
(avatar: CircleAvatar(
backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
child: Text('AB'),
),
label: Text('Aaron Burr'),)
```

Also, you can build the chatbot using Dialogflow and provide the option buttons to the user.

There are many ways to add the option buttons such as custom payload, Google assistant, etc. Using [custom payload](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-rich-messages#custom) you can add your custom rich message type.

Comment: Ya but the problem was how to access the custom payload in the flutter app.

Comment: You will have to just add the custom payload in the Dialogflow so platforms like Kommunicate will render the rich messages on your flutter app once you do the chat integration on your flutter app.

Comment: How would I call the rendered message from Kommunicate in flutter then ?